# Android TV App Installation

Tags: android, android-tv

Does anyone know how to install an App on the Android TV Developer Box? Since there is no browser it is not possible to install it from an email. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ADB to do this.

First, connect your ADT-1 to a computer via USB.

Make sure your USB Drivers are up-to-date from the SDK manager. Also make sure that you've enabled **USB Debugging** in **Settings > Preferences > Developer options > Debugging**.

Then run `adb devices`. You should see your device information there. If so, it's connected via ADB to your computer.

Then, do `adb install /path/to/apk/myapk.apk`. This will install the app to your ADT-1.